# Isabelle Server on another machine?

Tags: isabelle

I want to use Isabelle on weaker laptops and delegate the heavy theorem search/proving to a server on the network. I would guess that this has been done before but I could not find tutorials or reports for this task.

The [Isabelle System Manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/system.pdf#chapter.4) describes how to run the Isabelle backend on its own. However I don't understand from the manual how to connect one of the existing frontends (e.g. [Isabelle/jEdit](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/jedit.pdf)) to such a process. The setup should ideally work for multiple users (and with theory files located on the user system).

The best I could achieve up to now was to run all of Isabelle/jEdit on the server and access it from a Linux laptop via SSH/X11-forwarding. This is cool but not exactly what I had in mind. Are there other approaches?

Comment: What might work for you is to [use a remote build (links to pdf)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.07195.pdf). Using builds (even locally) already saves me a lot of start-up time and memory, at the expense of it being more involved to edit built files. Your current session would still run on your local laptop though, so this isn't exactly what you asked for. Makarius has [outlined his ideas in a pdf](http://sketis.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Isabelle_Scaling_Dec-2017.pdf) on how to improve your experience back in 2017, but I don't know its current state.